# When I ran selenium test case the page is not loaded, when i checked it manually it's works

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

- I wrote selenium test cases for submit button in sample website. Here I am facing a problem like, when I click on submit button results are not coming, while it happens only when I execute selenium test case. but manually I checked it, results are coming fastly. How to overcome this problem.
  selenium version - 3.6.0
  Google chrome version - 59.0.3071.86.
  can anyone help this? How to overcome this problem.

Comment: Your question is too abstract. Share the error stacktrace/ your code snippets and application's HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

It could be cookies issues.
Try to clean your browser cookies then load the page or try to load the page multiple times on selenium driver.

Answer (score -1):

use throws InterruptedException method

add this after click on submit button 
example:-

```
driver.findElement(By.id("submitid")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Hope this work!!